# I cant boot with windows anymore, help!

Tags: 12.10

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 desktop 32 bit version along with my windows 7 ultimate 32bit version( which already existed). I think when installing with the option in the installer it asked which one to boot with i think i gave windows loader, and now when i restart i get Ubuntu, advanced Ubuntu,... and the last one is windows loader i tried clicking it , it just enters and is it is again back to the same page, can i now boot with windows or have i done a mistake somewhere. plz help me and if i have mistaken please correct me.

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu using the option in installer (which says install ubuntu alongside Windows 7) or using the advanced tool during Ubuntu setup? 

People usually get this problem when they delete the Windows 7 bootloader partition during Ubuntu setup.

Comment: Still didnt fixed? See answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes making Dual Boot was needed grub recovery. 
But this time you maybe did change bootloader to install not in HDD but in HDD windows partition so it loads partitions and then boots in Windows partition where you put bootloader and selecting windows partition it loads again because of such misconfiguration.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

First try just https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Theres written to install https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

And then recommended repair. Then restart to test.
If didn't fixed then advanced and put bootloaded in sda not sda1 or sda2

Comment: Thanks for your reply but still cant make my way i find them complicated what is Grub and find it a hell confusing can someone give me easy reply in layman terms plz! Don't laugh.

Comment: Oh you just open this link in Ubuntu and read it. Theres written how to install and i pasted that to you and then will open that programm with that one big command line and youll have 2 buttons as in picture in link about Boot-Repair. So u press just Recommended repair. Try that 1st and then Grub bootloader will be repaired and it should work. If not come back and try again with other Advanced option.

Comment: It says me to download entire ubuntu and the boot repair , my net connection is slow so can i have the link for only boot repair? (32bit version)

Comment: It recommends but it will not couse the commands i gave are just for doing what they mean and nothing else. They are for adding boot-repair developer link and checking for new updates and installing that boot-repair and opening it. On part of install it recommends for updates but wont do them. It will do just installing boot-repair.